# Simple PHP Form SQL Insert

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with a very basic issue that I cannot resolve.
A bit of background: I have a PHP form and I would like the information inside the table to insert into my SQL table. For some reason, when I hit submit nothing inserts into the table and I have no idea why. Please help!
This is the PHP Code:

```
<?php 
try
    {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $Database_Host . ';dbname=' . $Database_Database, $Database_Username, $Database_Password);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die("Failed to connect to database! Please check the database settings.");
    }
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {  
     $result = mysql_query('INSERT INTO requests (song,name,dedicated,time) VALUES ("' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) . '", "' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dedicated']) . '", "' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['song']) . '", UNIX_TIMESTAMP())'); 
    if ($result) { 
        echo 'Song requested successfully!<br />'; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

This is the HTML Code:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">Request:<br /><br /> 
Song:<br /> 
<input type="text" name="song"><br /> 
Name:<br /> 
<input type="text" name="name"><br /> 
Comments:<br /> 
<input type="text" name="dedicated"><br /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

What this is meant to do is insert the request form into the SQL table, however nothing is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Edward

Comment: You're mixing mysql_ and PDO. Don't.

Comment: Should I just remove the PDO catch then?

Comment: you are using pdo and can NOT use mysql_query() . use $db->query() instead

Comment: You have to pay attention to the order of fields you defined after table name

Comment: Since you're using PDO, you should use a prepared query instead of substituting into the SQL string.

Comment: Stick with PDO. The mysql_ functions are deprecated, and have been removed from PHP7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix mysql and PDO like that. You should use a PDO prepared query for the insert.

Also, the order of the values in the `VALUES` list have to match the column list -- you had the values in the order `name, dedicated, song, time` instead of `song, name, dedicated, time`.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    try
    {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $Database_Host . ';dbname=' . $Database_Database, $Database_Username, $Database_Password);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die("Failed to connect to database! Please check the database settings.");
    }
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO requests (song,name,dedicated,time) VALUES (:song, :name, :dedicated, UNIX_TIMESTAMP())'); 
    $result = $stmt->execute(array(':song' => $_POST['song'], ':name' => $_POST['name'], ':dedicated' => $_POST['dedicated']));
    if ($stmt->rowCount == 1) {
        echo "Song requested successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Song could not be requested";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, so how would I relate the if statement to the submit button of the form? I have set the variables however cannot figure out how to apply them to the completion of the HTML Form.

Comment: Test whether `$_POST['submit']` is set, so you know that the form was submitted. This is basic PHP form processing, any tutorial should include code like this. I've updated the answer.

Comment: For some reason, it's throwing a 500 internal error now.
The full code is located here if you can spot anything out: http://pastebin.com/egXwvyCk
Thanks again!

Comment: The reason for the error will be in your apache log. What is it?

Comment: I was missing a `)` on the `execute` line, I've fixed it.

Comment: SO's editor doesn't detect mismatched brackets. But when you're programming you should use one that does.

Comment: Alright! It inserted into the table, however the time stamp is NULL and it echoed "Song could not be requested", however everything else seems to function. :)

Comment: What's the datatype of the `time` column? `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is an integer. If you want a datetime, you should use `NOW()`.

Comment: Good point, the datatype is DATE and not INT. I'll change that now.

Answer (score 0):

You should study about `pdo` and `mysql` and then use them ...
just see this simple example with mysql :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);

// set parameters and execute
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "john@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

$firstname = "Mary";
$lastname = "Moe";
$email = "mary@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

$firstname = "Julie";
$lastname = "Dooley";
$email = "julie@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

and this one with pdo :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare sql and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email)");
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

// insert a row
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "john@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row
$firstname = "Mary";
$lastname = "Moe";
$email = "mary@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row
$firstname = "Julie";
$lastname = "Dooley";
$email = "julie@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

I prefer using pdo

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

**NOTE :**  use prepared statements to avoid sql injection .

Comment: If you're not going to show how to write the code correctly, this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help, can you write an answer for me so I can study and learn from my mistakes easier? Thank you ;)

Comment: @Barmar just want to help in few time